# Selenium Grid + Maven + TestNG + Extent Reports + Parallel Testing

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, grid, selenium-extent-report

I searched for a specific documentation which explains steps to set up the Selenium Grid with Maven, Extent Reports and Parallel Testing from scratch which will be very helpful for us. Kindly help to get a documentation or refer some websites. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed below steps for setting up Selenium Grid and doing testing on multiple machines. The system I used was Mac so all commands are related to Mac OS.
The project I have used was a maven project with Extent Report configured in it.

Try doing below steps for setup and see if it works for you:

1. Open website seleniumhq.ord and download the selenium-standalone server version 2.53.0 (This is because the same selenium version is used in the framework)
2. Next copy the downloaded jar and place it to different folder
3. Then open the terminal or command prompt and type below command: java -jar (location+name of the selenium standalone server) -role hub
4. java -jar /Users/abcd/Desktop/efgh/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role hub will be the ideal format of the command. By doing this we are making our system as HUB and now we require NODE's for performing testing.
5. Once the Hub is created then open browser and type http://localhost:4444/grid/consoles
6. When you open it for the first time them it will give info of selenium server being used and linked text “console”.
7. The page is blank because we do not have any node till now. So next we will create Nodes. Follow below command:
   java -jar /Users/abcd/Desktop/efgh/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role node –hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
8. In place localhost we can write the IP of the machine which we want to connect.

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. Successfully implemented grid with parallel testing and extent report v4.